# Where i can get free multi vendor module for magento 2.3.5 version?

Tags: magento2, multi-vendor

I would like to know if you guys know there is any website which provides modules free for magento 2 especially multi vendor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my experience me not found free the multi-vendor extension because it is very popular or costly extension.But on GitHub i find **https://github.com/arunguru77/Magento-Multivendor** but he is magento 2 not proper 2.3.4.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was a treasure of modules.  You are a God.